# Flexbox set min-height despite height of contents

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a 2 column flexbox layout. The items in the columns use `flex:1` and I've only set their height using `min-height`. The idea is that both columns should always be of equal heigh. When colA is shorter than colB, the child-items of colA stretch to fill the avaliable height. When colA is taller than colB, the items of colB are as tall as their min-height.

The problem is that, as usual with css, if I have an element with `min-height: 100px` but fill it with contents which is 500px tall, that min-height will never be used, the effective min-height will be the height of the contents.(500px).

The question is : is there any way in flex make items collapse to their min-height despite the height of their contents?
I have an elements with `overflow-y:scroll; min-height: 100px`. I want to fill it with a bunch of contents without it expanding beyond 100px height unless it's parents column requires it to expand.

Updated with example https://jsbin.com/gicirabufe/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: So it will start to scroll you mean?

Comment: @LGSon - Exactly. Forgot to mention that.  I've set `overflow-y: scroll`. I'll add that clarification to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Here is a start for you.

The `scroll` element is necessary to be able to solve the scrolling you are looking (`flex` itself has some flaws making that not possible without)

`item2` is now set to only use as much space as its content, and this is as well needed or else the scroll won't kick properly on `item1`.

I added `min-height: 80px;` to `item1`, so when the content in `item2` gets bigger, it doesn't collapse totally. Play with that `min-height` value to fit your needs the best.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: lime;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 80px;
}
.item2 {
  flex: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.scroll {  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="left">
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
    Bla<br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="item1">
      <div class="scroll">
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      Bla 2<br>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<br>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="left">
    Bla<br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="item1">
      <div class="scroll">
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
        Bla 1<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      Bla 2<br>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: @Drkawashima Did yet another update ... looks more like your demo

Comment: @Drkawashima Did the update help you moving forward?